# Spring boot soap ws error while deploying as war

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap, war

I am new to spring boot. Tried a simple example for spring boot soap ws. Works fine when packaged as jar but when packaged as war and deployed in application server (wildly-16.0.0 Betal) not getting deployed. Getting error handler not found.Debugged a lot but unable to find solution. All main classes are in the same package.Could you please help me out to solve this issue?

I used example from below link,
https://codenotfound.com/spring-ws-example.html

But while creating war file made the below changes,
pom.xml

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
    <!-- ... -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
           <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
           <version>3.0</version>
           <scope>provided</scope>
       </dependency>
        <!-- ... -->
    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>spring-snapshots</id>
                <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
                <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>spring-milestones</id>
                <name>Spring Milestones</name>
                <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
        <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>spring-snapshots</id>
                <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
                <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </pluginRepository>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>spring-milestones</id>
                <name>Spring Milestones</name>
                <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>
```

SpringWsApplication.java

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootWsApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(SpringBootWsApplication.class);
    }

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(SpringBootWsApplication.class, args);
}
```

}

application.properties

```
server.servlet-path=/*
```